# Discord.py run 2 instances of a bot in a script

Tags: python, discord, python-asyncio, discord.py

I have a discord bot that needs to run in a while(True) loop, as well as still receive commands. The only way I think I can do this that works with my program would be to have 2 separate instances of the bot running. Like saying:

```
import discord
import time
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!');       
client2= commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.');
channel = client.get_channel(734106469343249954)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    time.Sleep(5)
    while(True):
        await channel.send("Sent message")

@client2.command()
async def a(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Send")
```

and then at the bottom:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(client.start('Token'))
loop.create_task(client2.start('Token'))
loop.run_forever()
```

I tried this, and it didn't work. What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to run 2 bots, or the same bot twice from one script?

I need one of the instances to be in a while(True) loop.

When I try this I get loop starting and am able to call the `.a` command until the loop starts, but afterwards, it gives me no response.

How can I run 2 instances of a bot in a script, and keep one in a loop while letting the other one to listen to commands?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you don't need 2 bots to do this. Second what you're doing is actually API abuse. There are rate limits on sending messages, per channel and global, and abusing this is reason for them to reset your token/delete the application. So I'm not exactly sure of your issue, but if I was I also wouldn't help you abuse the API.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `time.sleep` which will freeze your bot and not accept any other input during that time. Use `await asyncio.sleep(5)` instead. You can remove that `client2` thing and just keep `client` for both your on_ready event and your command. For what you're trying to do, this might be helpful for you:

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')
channel = client.get_channel(734106469343249954)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Hello')

@client.listen()
async def background():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    while not client.is_closed():
        await channel.send("Sent message")


@client.command()
async def a(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Send")

client.loop.create_task(background())
client.run('--Token--')
```

I don't think you would need to run 2 instances of the bot to do what you want. I hope this helps :p

Answer (score 0):

well yea wtf is this you're message spamming a server
no spoon feed for you but problem is youre using while True, never do that. do x = True, while x: instead. and time.Sleep, thats a blocking command that may make your bot disconnect from websocket. instead of time.Sleep you should import asyncio and await asyncio.sleep(5).